# Интеграция двух сайтов wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api

есть два сайта на WordPress, у первого сайта есть API.
Как сделать так, чтобы после оплаты на первом сайте услуг, было перенаправление на второй сайт и форма Входа на втором сайте была автоматически заполнена данными клиента который произвел оплату?
Вариантов у меня нет пока, мало опыта.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь!
Всем хорошего дня.

Comment: Начать нужно отсель https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

Нуу передачу параметров пользователя можно попробовать организовать через GET параметры.
Я бы посмотрел в сторону такого "сценария": После оплаты ( если ты можешь получить статус ее конечно) JSом генерировать ссылку на второй сайт где в качестве GET параметров указывать данные клиента ,который произвел оплату и перекидывать его через `window.open` или `location.href`. А на втором сайте ,тем же JSом "парсить" URL и полученными данными заполнять поля формы входа.

Как то так.